# Fix ownership issue with Titanium Backup creating backups with media_rw as the ownership

Tags: android-11, titanium-backup, android-12

Normally, Titanium Backup saves backups with its ownership. For example, `u0_a252`:

```
-rw------- 1 u0_a252  u0_a252   539 2021-11-07 09:52 com.application.zomato-20211107-095236.properties
```

However, it sometimes saves backups with `media_rw` ownership:

```
-rw------- 1 media_rw media_rw 963K 2021-11-07 09:00 net.bikerouteplanner-667db7c2a87ed259454c457130013a1a.apk.bz2
```

The backup directory is in `/sdcard/`, internal storage.

These files can't be read by users or even by root. It prevents me from easily syncing the files to an external server or copying them off before doing a factory reset.

I've tried `chown` in `adb` with `su`, but the ownership isn't changed.  The solution I've found is to reboot to the bootloader, boot TWRP, and change it in an `adb shell`.

I've found nothing in web searches other than to use TWRP. I found nothing going to the cause of the bad ownership other than perhaps android taking them as media files. I believe the problem started with Android 11.
I am currently running Android 11 on a Pixel 5, rooted with Magisk.

Comment: reboot should fix this

Comment: Reboot doesn't fix it.  I rebooted dozens of times trying to find a solution.

Comment: I also went all the way back to a factory reset phone.  When I uploaded the backup files I fixed the ownership in TWRP's adb.  TB uses its ownership 95% of the time.  I haven't found correlation between the an app's attributes and the bad ownership.

Comment: the bad files always have the .apk.bz2 extension.  When I used gzip compression, I believe the bad files were with the apk.gz extension.

Comment: Thought this is fixed automatically since Oreo. try [manually](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2222297)

Comment: If you can't solve it let me advertise [Migrate](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763) alternative

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to migrate.  TB has the look of an app that hasn't been updated in ages.

Comment: Migrate is more handy when you are "migrating" to another ROM. Titanium has the unappealing UI since long but it doesn't seem to be actively developed anymore // It wouldn't run on Android 11//I switched to [swift backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.swiftapps.swiftbackup)//Titanium hasn't been updated for two years now;two years is a long long time in mobile app world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround/solution.

Go into Titanium Backup, Preferences, Backup folder location.  Change the storage provider to "DocumentProvider" storage which shows up as 'External Storage.'

It's important that 'use the current folder' be used in the selection.  I let it be set to the storage root (`/sdcard/`), then set it back to my Titanium Backup folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://xdaforums.com/t/solved-cant-copy-titanium-backup-files-to-pc.4257023/post-85691869). It's frustratingly simple:

```
$ adb shell
$ su -
# cd /sdcard/TitaniumBackup
# chgrp "$(find . -maxdepth 0 -printf '%g')" ./*
```